# Find $\liminf X_n$ where $X_n=1_{[n,n+1]}$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

My attempt:
Suppose $\omega=n_0$. Then choose $N\geq n_0+1$.Threfore, $X_N(\omega)=0$. Therefore, $\inf_{k\geq N}X_k(\omega)=0$.
Does it suffice to prove that $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n=0$?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the pointwise limit inferior, then in this case it is even simpler than that: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n = 0$ pointwise, which one proves as you did: let $\omega$ be given and pick $N > \omega + 2$. Then, for all $n \geq N$, $\omega < \lfloor N \rfloor$ and so $X_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}(\omega) = 0$. Since this holds for *all* sufficiently large $n$, $X_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise.

[*I should mention that proving the limit exists implies the liminf exists, because the limit exists if and only if both the liminf and limsup are equal, in which case they equal the limit. I find it's simpler because you don't have to deal with limits of infs.*]

On the other hand, to finish off your proof you simply need to note that $0$ is an upper bound for the $\liminf$, that the sequence $\inf_{k\geq n} X_k$ is non-decreasing in $n$, and that the upper bound 0 is achieved for $n \geq N$. This forces
$$0 \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) \leq 0.$$